# How to add missing http:// to an anchor in a string - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a code which adds hyperlink to all plain text where it finds `http://` or `https://`. The code works pretty well for `https://www.google.com` and `http://yahoo.com`. It converts these text into clickable hyperlink with correct address.

```
<?php
function convert_text_to_link($str)
{
    $pattern = "/(?:(https?):\/\/([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])/i"; 
    return preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>", $str);
}

$str = "https://www.google.com is the biggest search engine. It's competitors are http://yahoo.com and www.bing.com.";
echo convert_text_to_link($str);
?>
```

But when my code sees `www.bing.com`, though it adds hyperlink to it but the `href` attribute also becomes `www.bing.com`. There is no `http://` prepended it. Therefore the link becomes unusable without the link `http://localhost/myproject/www.bing.com` will go nowhere.

How can I add `http://` to `www.bing.com` so that it should become `http://www.bing.com`?

Comment: This could be even shorter  `echo preg_replace('~(?:http(s?)://|(www\.))(\S+)(?<![.,:])~', "<a href='http$1://$2$3' target='_blank'>$0</a>", $str);`

Comment: Absolutely! good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your function. Try this.

```
function convert_text_to_link($str) {
    $pattern = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
    return preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank">$0</a>', $str);
}
```

Comment: @user5307298 Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try and check if this works:

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/^www./, 'https:');
```

might be you will get your solution.

I just got to know about some other approaches too, you can try them out as per your code and requirements:

1.

```
str_replace("www.","http://","$str");
```

The test here is case-sensitive. This means that if the string is initially  this will change it to http://Http://example.com which is probably not what you want.

2. try regex:

`if (!$str.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//))
 {
    $str = 'http://' + $str;
 }`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah this first approach works, but you will need to work around it as per your requirements.

Comment: It's PHP, NOT JavaScript!

Comment: ohh my bad sry.